# Using Component inside AuthorizeView in Blazor webassembly, ElementReference is Null

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I use this markup in my layout page:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>        
        <AppToolBar />
        <SoftwareDesktop @ref="Desktop" RenderCache=@true />
        <CascadingValue Name="Desktop" TValue="object" Value="@this">            
            @Body            
        </CascadingValue>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>        
            <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=@navigateToLoginPage>                
                Login
            </button>
        </p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I want when user is authorized this element reference call a method:

```
public SoftwareDesktop Desktop { get; private set; } = null!;
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
 {
     await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
     if (firstRender)
     {
         if (Desktop != null)
             FillMenu();
     }
 }

private void FillMenu()
{
    var menu = Desktop.Menu.DataSource.Add("Menu1", Icons.Material.Filled.Build, string.Empty);
    menu.Childs.Add("Chart", Icons.Material.Filled.InsertChart, "/fetchdata");
    menu.Childs.Add("Profile", Icons.Material.Filled.AccessAlarm, string.Empty);
    menu.Childs.Add("MyAccount", Icons.Material.Filled.Accessible, string.Empty);
    Desktop.Menu.Refresh();
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

But when the user is authorized, The **Desktop Reference** is still null, How to solve this problem? (Note: inside Desktop component is a public method that is called through the desktop element reference).

**EDIT**

After login, When I navigate to this page without refresh, @ref="Desktop" executed first and then onafterrender(firstRender) and everything is good.

But when I refresh the page (although authorization still work), But OnAfterRender(firstRender) executed first following by @ref="Desktop". This is blazor webassembly, is it by design and has no way to correct this?